# Graph coloring problem. Let $G$ be $|V(G)| = n$ and $k$-colorable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be $|V(G)| = n$ and $k$-colorable. Show that G has a
independent set with at least $\frac{n}{k}$
vertices.

An Independt set is a set of vettex that have the same color such that for every 2 vertex there is not an edge between them 
 I have drawn some graphs and this indeed is true, but how can I prove it? By contradiction, I was thinking using the fact that if $G$ is $k$-chromatic then $G$ has $k$ vertices of degree at least $k-1$

Comment: What does order of a graph mean? Is it the number of vertices?

Answer (score 3):

Color the vertices of the graph with $k$ colors such that no two adjacent vertices have the same color. This gives a parition of $V(G)$ into $k$ parts $P_1, \ldots, P_k$ with the property that any two vertices in a given part have the same color.
Therefore every $P_i$ is an endependent set. Now since $|P_1|+\cdots+|P_k| = |V(G)| = n$, we see that there must be $1\leq i\leq k$ such that $|P_i|\geq n/k$ and we are done.